# How to set the expiration date for a Rails session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4 is it possible to set a (far) expiration date for a session so that it is persistent?

I know it is possible for cookies, so, given that sessions are based on cookies, I would like to change the expiration date. How to set that for a single session and how to configure the environment for all sessions?

P.S. I want to use sessions instead of cookies because in Rails are secure by default.

Answer (score 3):

Aware of possible security implications, here's the solution I found:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :expire_after => 1.year
```